# Python: How to get correct time despite wrong PC time?

Tags: python, datetime

Suppose, it's originally **18:00 (06:00 PM)**  right now. But the time of my PC is **17:29 (05:29 PM)**.

Now my code works like:

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> str(datetime.now())
'2021-10-20 17:29:28.653283'
```

How can I get a datetime object that will return the original datetime i.e. **18:00 (06:00 PM)**.

Something like:

```py
'2021-10-20 18:00:00.653283'
```

**Important: Whatever the PC time is I need to get the original time. So changing the PC time is not an option.**

Comment: If your PC does not have the correct time, then it can't give you the correct time. You'd need to fetch the correct time from some external system that actually has the correct time. Unless you happen to know by how much your system is off, then you can compensate for that obviously. But presumably you can't know that reliably.

Comment: you could query an NTP server directly, for example there's [ntplib](https://pypi.org/project/ntplib/) for Python. However, if you have internet access, you could as well properly set & sync your machine's clock.

Answer (score 0):

X/Y problem - maybe your pc needs the time synchronized? Check the calendar settings and ensure synchronization servers are working. Try synchronizing manually.
It could be weak CMOS battery or oscillator/timer issue with the motherboard, if your pc time drifts away over time.
Also note that wrong time will make some browser connections fail (I do not know how big time difference causes it).

---

Is your program communicating with anything outside the machine? If not, why do you need exact objective time?

If you do communicate with anything over web - you can query the well known time servers like nist.gov, but remember to account for delays and so on, you also have to store the offset to reuse it in future or query servers every time.

If your program does not need to communicate, consider whether absolute objective time is really needed. In isolated system, you can't really tell, nor you usually need to.